# Defining custom request - Swagger (Drf-yasg)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger-ui, drf-yasg

I have a use case, where the request required fields are different depending on one of the field values of the request.

For example, if the value of the movable type in the request is `'P'`, then some fields are mandatory, otherwise, if the value of the move type is `'D'`, then some of the other fields are mandatory.

How to create a custom request for such a use case using `drf-yasg` ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I found in [drf_yasg docs](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) you need to implement a concept called *`Inspector` classes* to customize behavior related to a specific field, serializer, filter, or paginator classes you can implement the `FieldInspector`, `SerializerInspector`, `FilterInspector`, `PaginatorInspector` classes and use them with [`@swagger_auto_schema`](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html#custom-spec-swagger-auto-schema) or one of the [`related settings`](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/settings.html#default-class-settings).

Here is an example that is a `FieldInspector` that removes the title attribute from all generated Schema objects and taken from [**`Inspector` classes** <sup>[drf_yasg-docs]</sup>](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html#inspector-classes) :

> ```py
> from drf_yasg.inspectors import FieldInspector
>
> class NoSchemaTitleInspector(FieldInspector):
>   def process_result(self, result, method_name, obj, **kwargs):
>      # remove the `title` attribute of all Schema objects
>      if isinstance(result, openapi.Schema.OR_REF):
>         # traverse any references and alter the Schema object in place
>         schema = openapi.resolve_ref(result, self.components)
>         schema.pop('title', None)
>
>         # no ``return schema`` here, because it would mean we always generate
>         # an inline `object` instead of a definition reference
>
>      # return back the same object that we got - i.e. a reference if we got >a reference
>      return result
>
>
> class NoTitleAutoSchema(SwaggerAutoSchema):
>   field_inspectors = [NoSchemaTitleInspector] + >swagger_settings.DEFAULT_FIELD_INSPECTORS
>
> class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
>   swagger_schema = NoTitleAutoSchema
>   ...
> ```